# Choice command equivalent for Powershell allowing over 254 characters

Tags: powershell, input, command, command-line-tool

Is there a choice command equivalent for Powershell that can allow over the 254 character limit? As the choice command functions, it only allows specified characters. Such as in the example below, only the Y or N characters can be typed.

```
choice /C YN /M "Y or N?"
if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 2) {
    Write-Output "You said N"
}
elseif ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 1) {
    Write-Output "You said Y"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To spell it out: the `/m` parameter of [`choice.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/choice), which specifies the prompt message, is limited to 254 characters, and `choice.exe` *fails* with longer arguments.

To overcome this limit, you don't need an alternative to `choice.exe`, however:

- Use [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host)`-NoNewLine` to print your 254+-character message, followed by a space.
- Then call `choice.exe` *without* `/m`:

For instance:

```bash
Write-Host -NoNewLine ('x' * 254 + '! ')
choice /c yn
```